# transaction receipt was not generated after 600 seconds for transaction

Tags: go-ethereum, web3j

I am running private ethereum blockchain using geth and I am using web3j to send transactions. Since yesterday I am not able to deploy my contract, In my java console I am getting "transaction receipt was not generated after 600 seconds for transaction" while I can see using block explorer that the contract is created in my blockchain.

```
String contractAddress = myContract.deploy(web3j, credentials, DefaultGasProvider.GAS_PRICE, DefaultGasProvider.GAS_LIMIT, BigInteger.valueOf(campaign.getId()),
                        campaign.getName(), startDateTime, endDateTime).send().getContractAddress();
```

Here is my genesis file code

```
{
"config": {  
        "chainId": 987, 
        "homesteadBlock": 0,
        "eip150Block": 0,
        "eip155Block": 0,
        "eip158Block": 0
    },
    "nonce": "0x0000000000000042",
    "timestamp": "0x0",
    "parentHash": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
    "extraData": "0x00",
    "gasLimit": "0x8000000",
    "difficulty": "0x400",
    "mixhash": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
    "coinbase": "0x3333333333333333333333333333333333333333",
    "alloc": {
    }
}
```

I am using following command to run blockchain

```
geth --datadir ~/chaindata/ --networkid 12345 --verbosity 3 --rpc --port 30304 --rpcport 8545 --rpcaddr "<private IP>" --rpccorsdomain "http://<private IP>:8080,  http://<private IP>:8000" --rpcapi "web3,eth,personal,net"  --preload "/home/ubuntu/scripts/mineWhenNeeded.js" --nodiscover  --gcmode archive  --allow-insecure-unlock > ~/myLogs/bcLogs.out 2>&1 &
```

Also, my miner was creating so many blank blocks so I have used following script to mine the blocks when only needed

```
var minimum_confirmations = 3;
var mining_threads = 1
var txBlock = 0
function checkWork() {
    if (eth.getBlock("pending").transactions.length > 0) {
        txBlock = eth.getBlock("pending").number
        if (eth.mining) return;
        console.log("  Transactions pending. Mining...");
        miner.start(mining_threads)
        interval = setInterval(function () {
            if (eth.getBlock("latest").number < txBlock + minimum_confirmations) {
                if (eth.getBlock("pending").transactions.length > 0) txBlock = eth.getBlock("pending").number;
            } else {
                console.log(minimum_confirmations + " confirmations achieved; mining stopped.");
                miner.stop()
                clearInterval(interval);
            }
        }, 600)
    }
}

eth.filter("latest", function (err, block) { checkWork(); });
eth.filter("pending", function (err, block) { checkWork(); });

checkWork();
```

Also, my average blocktime is getting too higher its 38.9 minute now. How to reduce the average blocktime?

Answer (score 1):

Set `gasPrice` and `gas` for your transaction by hand. Do not trust gas price estimators wallets and nodes are using. Check ethgasstation.info/ for the current network status.

Also, I am not expert on web3j but on web3.js you can tune various timeouts used by the library.